# Same scaling for x-axis and y-axis in list_plot

Tags: plot, sage

I'm using `list_plot` in sage to plot a list of points. How can I set the scaling of the x-axis and y-axis the same? In my plots the unit square is actually a wide rectangle. I want it to remain a square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the parameter  `aspect_ratio` to 1. Example:

```
list_plot([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9], aspect_ratio=1)
```

[image: list plot]

Documentation: [2D Plotting](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plotting/sage/plot/plot.html)

Comment: Thanks. I looked in the documentation as well but only searched for scaling.